# on using angular 5 httpclient , changing from response.json() to just response throws compilation error

Tags: angular, angular5, angular-httpclient

I am in the process of upgrading angular app from version 4 to 5 and using httpclient. However when i try to change the response.json() to just response but it does not compile

I have my rest service which handles all the get and post calls

```
        import { Injectable } from '@angular/core'
        import { Response } from '@angular/http';
        import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
        import { Headers, RequestOptions } from '@angular/http';
        import { Error } from './Error';
        import { Router } from '@angular/router';
        import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';
        import { LocalStorageWrapperModule } from '../../core/services/local-storage-module.service';

        const httpOptions = {
            headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8' })
        };

        @Injectable()
        export class RestModuleService {
            private self: any;
            private observable: any;

            constructor(private httpService: HttpClient, private router:Router, private storage:LocalStorageWrapperModule) {
                this.self = this;
            }

            get(inURL, config = undefined) {
                let headers, options;
                if (config){
                    options = config;
                } else {
                    options = httpOptions;
                }

                let action = this.httpService.get(inURL, options);
                return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                    action.subscribe(
                        response => resolve(response),
                        error => {
                            this.interceptError(error);
                            reject(error);
                        }
                    );
                });
            }

            post(inURL, data, config = undefined) {
                let headers, options;
                if (config){
                    options = config;
                } else {
                    options = httpOptions;
                }
                options = { ...options, observe: 'response' };

                let action = this.httpService.post(inURL, data, options);
                return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                    action.subscribe(
                        response => resolve(response),
                        error => {
                            this.interceptError(error);
                            reject(error);
                        }
                    );
                });
            }
        }
```

I am consuming the rest service to make an api call here

```
        import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
        import { RestModuleService } from '../../../../shared/services/rest-module.service';
        import { InternalErrorService } from '../../../../shared/services/internal-error.service';
        import * as Utilities from '../../../../shared/services/utilities';

        const VIEW_API_BASE = Utilities.vlsiURLWithHost();

        @Injectable()
        export class BasicInfoService {
            constructor(
                private restService: RestModuleService,
                private internalError: InternalErrorService
            ) {}

            getPerformanceBasicInfo(sessionId) {
                const url = BASE + 'perf/getDiProtocolData';
                let data = {
                    id: sessionId
                };
                return this.restService.post(url, JSON.stringify(data))
                    .then((response: Response) => response.json())
                    .catch((error) => this.internalError.show());
            }
        }
```

I changed this to  send the response.body as the post call gives the entire response including the headers

```
         getPerformanceBasicInfo(sessionId) {
                const url = BASE + 'perf/getDiProtocolData';
                let data = {
                    id: sessionId
                };
                return this.restService.post(url, JSON.stringify(data))
                    .then((response) => response.body)
                    .catch((error) => this.internalError.show());
            }
```

One additional method is

```
     getSiteList(): Promise<SiteInfo[]> {
    const url = BASE + '/site/list';
    return this.restService.get(url)
        .then((response: Response) => {
            return response.json().map((s: SiteInfo) => {
                s.numPods = s.pods && s.pods.length || 0;
                return s;
            })
        }).catch(error => this.internalError.show());
}
```

Here the response is jsonified and then we use .map , but once i remove the .json() it throws a compile error again that .map is not a function on response

it fails to compile with the reason [ts] Property 'body' does not exist on type '{}'.

How should this be corrected ???

Comment: Does the JSON contain a property called `body`? If not, there is no need to do `response.body`, as it already contains the parsed JSON

Comment: teh post method observes the complete response including the response headers. so the httpresponse has the headers and teh actual response comes back in the body

Comment: Oh okay, I missed that. Have you tried doing `response: Response` so that it knows what type it is?

Comment: do you want the full response ? if you don't want please remove , observe: 'response'. it will return entire response from the server

Comment: if you remove the observe:response , you will get the response as data only

Comment: need the observe: response  for inspecting the token and appending with every request

Comment: i just edited the question, the .map() function also does not work ....

Comment: @looneytunes You don't need to call .json on response explicitly , httpclient automatically take care of it

Comment: yes , i understand , but how would i make this work in angular 5 where the data is a json object  to use .map()

Comment: Object doesn't have a `map` function. Arrays do, and so do `Observable`s. What are you trying to do

Comment: @looneytunes you have to use pipe operator

Comment: Please, read the guide and the documentation. None of the classes in the @angular/http module should be used. https://angular.io/guide/http

Comment: @NinjaJami The `restService.get` function returns a `Promise` in the above code

Comment: @user184994 one option would be convert to observables.  var observable= from(promise) ;

Comment: @looneytunes if you want to continue with promise , make sure that response is an array, then only you can apply javascript map function. if you are using observables you can take the advantage of rxjs observables operator like map

Comment: @looneytunes my suggestion would be either use promise or observables. Recommended observables. Currently you are using both observables and a promise on your RestModuleService.

Comment: @NinjaJami, i cannot change the restmoduleservice, however if i need to map my response from the promise  here to an array , how would i do that ?   also in teh current code it gets the response and converts it to an array of objects , but if httpclient already handles teh jsonification, why does .map() not work on it

Comment: @looneytunes you can apply the map function on your RestModuleService before you subscribe.  action.pipe(map( //apply the mapping code)).subscribe(//here response you will get)

Comment: @NinjaJami, Thanks , however i cannot change the get method , as this is used across teh app , only for the specifc method , i will nee dteh map functionality , not for every response

Comment: @looneytunes then one option would be once the promise resolved , if the response is an array , apply javascript map function [].map() else you have to convert the response to an observable and apply map function

Comment: @looneytunes change like .then((response: SiteInfo[]) => {
            return response.map((s: SiteInfo) => {
                s.numPods = s.pods && s.pods.length || 0;
                return s;
            })
        })

Comment: @NinjaJami I did this , and its not showing any compile errors    .then((response: any) => {
                return response.map((s: SiteInfo) => {
                    s.numPods = s.pods && s.pods.length || 0;
                    return s;
                })
            }).catch(error => this.internalError.show());

Comment: as SiteInfo is an object and its throwing errors when i assign the response as of type SiteInfo[] export class SiteInfo {
    id: string;
    base: SiteBase;
    pods?: string[];
    numPods: number;
}    would this work ?